# How to remove commits that I pulled in from upstream/develop into feature-branch?

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-commit, git-fork

I am really new to git.

- I forked `upstream/develop` sometime back.
- Now I recently created a `feature-brach` on it to fix some stuff.
- After fixing the bug. I've yet not commited the changes.
- I pull from the `upstream/develop` to get the latest code.
- Lo and behold. I get around 31 changes, previous commits the author made on the `upstream/develop`.
- I have modified only 4 files.
- My 4 files are also automerged at this point.
- I only stage my 4 files and commit them.
- Now in the PR its showing 21 commits in my branch and my commit below it.

How do remove all those other commits from my feature-branch(they were pulled in from `upstram/develop`), also why are automerged changes are appearing in diff ?

Answer (score 1):

What has happened is that rather than doing what is called a 'rebase' you might have merged upstream/develop with your local feature branch. It's a rookie mistake.

Q- How do remove all those other commits from my feature-branch?
Easiest way is to

1. find the commit hash on your local feature branch (use git log and lookup your commit message / files you changed)
2. change to local develop branch, pull upstream/develop to sync local develop and upstream/develop
3. create a new branch in local, use the commit hash and pick that commit and put it in your local new branch.
4. you're ready to go.

Q- also why are automerged changes are appearing in diff ?
Commit hash is different.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to remove them. They're just merge commits used to keep your branch up to date with the original develop branch.